# Partial specialization on a property of a template argument

Tags: c++

Suppose that I have several types which have a bool property `isComplex`:

```
struct SimpleBar1 {
    static constexpr bool isComplex = false;
    // ...
};
struct ComplexBaz2 {
    static constexpr bool isComplex = true;
    // ...
};
```

I'd like to have a template, which is partially specialized on the complex-ness of the type:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo;

template <typename T>
class Foo<T_is_simple> {
    // implementation when T::isComplex is false
};
template <typename T>
class Foo<T_is_complex> {
    // implementation when T::isComplex is true
};
```

So, when I write `Foo<SimpleBar1>`, I'd like to use the first specialization. If I write `Foo<ComplexBaz2`, I'd like to have the second.

I know a technique to achieve this, but I don't really like it:

```
template <typename T, bool isComplex = T::isComplex>
class Foo;
```

Then this can be partially specialized on the second template parameter.  The reason I don't like this is that it has a second parameter which can be misused, nothing stops the user of the template to overrule the default value.

Another way I see is to not use partial specialization, but use alias:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo_Simple {
    // implementation when T::isComplex is false
};
template <typename T>
class Foo_Complex {
    // implementation when T::isComplex is true
};
template <typename T>
using Foo = std::conditional_t<T::isComplex, Foo_Complex<T>, Foo_Simple<T>>;
```

I don't consider this a good solution either, because the connection between `Foo_Simple` and `Foo_Complex` is somehow lost, they are not specializations of the same primary template. And their names are ugly (I need to partially specialize on more properties, so I'd have `Foo_AAA_BBB_CCC` kind of classes).

Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Are you using C++20?

Comment: @DrewDormann: Not yet, I'm on C++17. But if you have a C++20 solution, I'm also interested in that (so in the future I can move to a C++20 based solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++20 introduces the *requires-clause* specifically for providing template specialization without adding SFINAE-style additional template arguments.

```
template <typename T>
class Foo;

template <typename T>
requires T::isComplex
class Foo<T> {
    public:
    static constexpr auto test = "complex";
};

template <typename T>
requires (!T::isComplex)
class Foo<T> {
    public:
    static constexpr auto test = "simple";
};
```

[Live example](https://www.godbolt.org/z/9z8nebTaT)